# Completeness of two metrics in the same space

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $d, d'$ two metrics on the same space $X$, and suppose that $(X,d)$ is complete. I've read that if every ball
$B'_r(x_0)=\left\{x\in X | d'(x_0,x)<r\right\}$
is contained in a ball
$B_R(x_0)=\left\{x\in X | d(x_0,x)<R\right\}$,
then $(X,d')$ is also complete.
How does the completeness follow from the above property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $d$ is the discrete metric. Then it is complete of course. Moreover, for *any* metric $d'$, we have the property you described above (letting $R = 1.5$ for instance). But clearly there are non complete metrics. So what you say is not true.